# regex works when declared literally, but not when declared with new operator and variable value

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the string `input_value=`

```
<div href="asdf"></div>
<div href="1234"></div>
```

the replace pattern

```
var res = input_value.replace(/.+href="(\w+)".+/gm, "$1"); 
console.log(res) //=>asdf 1234
```

works as expected

However when I declare a  RegExp object with the `new` operator (as far as I know the only way to supply the regex with a dynamic element) the regex fails and I get the entire input_value returned:

```
var attribute = "href";
var re = new RegExp(".+" + attribute + "=\"(\w+)\".+", "gm"); 
var res = input_value.replace(re, "$1"); 
console.log(res) //=> <div href="asdf"></div>
                 //=> <div href="1234"></div>
```

What is the difference in how these two operate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try escaping the `\` in `\w`:

```
var re = new RegExp(".+" + attribute + "=\"(\\w+)\".+", "gm");
```

You need this because `\` is the escape character inside a string (e.g. `\"` escapes a literal `"`), so you need to escape it when you need to represent a literal `\`.

Comment: Thank you that works like a charm. Why do I need to escape it there?

Comment: Well, there it is, right there in the docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp Thanks again!

Comment: For the same reason you needed to escape the double quote: It has a special meaning for the string and therefore it needs to be escaped to maintain its "normal" meaning for the regex